# Greatest common divisor of $3$ numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, problem-solving

Let $a,b, c$ belong to $\mathbb Z$ such that $(a,b,c) \neq (0,0,0)$. Define the
[<s>highest common factor</s>] greatest common divisor ${\rm gcd}(a, b, c)$ to be the largest positive integer that divides $a, b$, and $c$.

> Prove that there are integers $s, t, u$, such that
>   $${\rm gcd}(a, b, c) = sa + tb + uc$$
>   Find such integers $s, t, u$ when $a = 91, b = 903, c = 1792$.

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_Lemma

Comment: I found the Highest Common Factor which is 7, and now I think I should work backwards, but I don't know how to do it with 3 numbers

Comment: @John note that the "highest common factor" is named _greatest common divisor_ and is denoted by ${\rm gcd}$.

Comment: @John See the link in my answer to the extended Euclidean algorithm. The method describe their also works to compute the Bezout identity for three numbers (or any finite number).

Answer (score 2):

Below is one conceptual way to prove [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for the gcd = hcf. For computation of the Bezout identity it is convenient to employ the [extended Euclidean algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

The set $\rm\,S\,$ of integers of form $\rm\,a\,x + b\,y+c\,z,\,\ x,y,z\in \mathbb Z,\,$ is closed under subtraction so, by the Lemma below, every positive $\rm\,n\in S\,$ is divisible by $\rm\,d = $ least positive $\rm\in S.\,$ So $\rm\,a,b\in S$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm d\mid a,b,\,$ i.e. $\rm\,d\,$ is a *common* divisor of $\rm\,a,b,\,$ and *greatest*: $\rm\ c\mid a,b\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,c\mid d = a\,x\!+\! b\,y\!+\!c\,z\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,c\le d.$

**Lemma** $\ \ $ Let $\,\rm S\ne\emptyset \,$ be a set of integers $>0$ closed under subtraction $> 0,\,$ i.e. for all $\rm\,n,m\in S, \,$ $\rm\ n > m\ \Rightarrow\  n-m\, \in\, S.\,$  Then every element of $\rm\,S\,$ is a multiple of the least element $\rm\:\ell = \min\, S.$

**Proof** ${\bf\ 1}\,\  $ If not there is a least nonmultiple $\rm\,n\in S,\,$ contra  $\rm\,n-\ell \in S\,$ is a nonmultiple of $\rm\,\ell.$

**Proof** ${\bf\ 2}\,\rm\,\ \   S\,$ closed under subtraction $\rm\,\Rightarrow\,S\,$ closed under remainder (mod), when it is $\ne 0,$ since mod may be computed by repeated subtraction, i.e. $\rm\, a\ mod\ b\, =\, a - k b\, =\, a-b-b-\cdots -b.\,$ Thus $\rm\,n\in S\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\, (n\ mod\ \ell) = 0,\,$ else it is $\rm\,\in S\,$ and smaller than $\rm\,\ell,\,$ contra mimimality of $\rm\,\ell.$

**Remark** $\ $ In a nutshell, two applications of induction yield the following inferences

$\ \ \rm\begin{eqnarray} S\ closed\ under\ {\bf subtraction} &\:\Rightarrow\:&\rm S\ closed\ under\ {\bf mod} = remainder = repeated\ subtraction \\
&\:\Rightarrow\:&\rm S\ closed\ under\ {\bf gcd} = repeated\ mod\ (Euclid's\ algorithm) \end{eqnarray}$

Interpreted constructively, this yields the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/23500) for the gcd. Namely, $ $ starting from the two elements of $\rm\,S\,$ that we know: $\rm\ a \,=\, 1\cdot a + 0\cdot b,\ \ b \,=\, 0\cdot a + 1\cdot b,\ $ we search for the least element of $\rm\,S\,$ by repeatedly subtracting elements of $\,\rm S\,$ to produce smaller elements of $\rm\,S\,$ (while keeping track of each elements linear representation in terms of $\rm\,a\,$ and $\rm\,b).\:$ This is essentially the *subtractive* form of the Euclidean algorithm (vs.  mod/remainder form).