# Prove that $s \not= \emptyset $ by showing that at least one of $|a|$ or $|b|$ is an element of $S$.

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, divisibility

.

I'm trying to show an alternative proof to Bezout's Lemma (let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then there exists $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $gcd(a, b) = ax + by$). Heres one of the steps in proving it:

a) Show the case where $a=b=0$. Then assume $a$ and $b$ are not both zero. Consider the set $S = $ {$s \in \mathbb{N} | \exists m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, s = ma+ nb $}. Prove that $s \not= \emptyset $ by showing that at least one of $|a|$ or $|b|$ is an element of $S$.

My work:

I'm assuming for $a=b=0$ we can just say that since $gcd(0,0)$ = $0$ and since $0x + 0y = 0$ then $gcd(0,0) = ax + by$ for $a=b=0$. And for the second part can you simply say if $a \not= 0$ and $b \not= 0$ and since $s = ma + nb$ then $|a|$ or $|b|$ must be in $S$?.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: $|a|=(\pm1)\cdot a+0\cdot b$, where the sign is chosen depending on $a\geq0$ or $a<0$.

Comment: would it be the same for |b| ? @ABC

Comment: More generally if nonempty $\,S\subset \Bbb Z\,$ is closed under subtraction then it has a nonnegative element. Being nonempty there exists $\,a\in S\,$ so either $\,a\ge 0\,$ or $\, (a-a)-a\, =\, -a \ge 0,\,$ i.e. closed under subtraction $\Rightarrow$ closed under negation.

Comment: so what does that mean @BillDubuque ? Why does being closed under subtraction mean anything?

Comment: @Alex Your set $\,S\,$ is closed under subtraction, and this is the *essence of the matter* in Bezout's Lemma (as one learns in abstract algebra when one studies *ideals*). See [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/691375/242)

Comment: Thanks @BillDubuque , so does that mean what you wrote earlier was the proof for this, cause as you can see I was no where close to that

Comment: @Alex That's one way. Another is to use $\,(a,b)= (a,b-a) = ax+(b-a)y = a(x-y)+by\ $ as the induction step.

Comment: @BillDubuque couldn't we just pick  m = 2 and m = 3, and this would show that it is non-empty, wouldn't finding a counter example suffice?

Comment: @user3182418 S is nonempty if there exists integers $\,m,n\,$ such that $\,ma+nb \in\Bbb N.$